# How to iterate over two byte slices

Tags: arrays, go, byte

Each byte slice represents a key,
I want to iterate from the lower key to the Upper Key
[pkg](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/)
https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/

Suppose there are two byte slices 
`lower :=[]byte`
`upper :=[]byte`
how do I do this?

```
   for i:=lower;i<upper;i++ {

    }
```

Example

```
 lower:= []byte{0,0,0,0,0,0}  // can be thought as 0 in decimal
 upper:= []byte{0,0,0,0,0,255} // can be thought as 255 in decimal
 //iterate over all numbers in between lower and upper
// {0,0,0,0,0,0} {0,0,0,0,0,1} ... {0,0,0,0,0,2} ..{0,0,0,0,0,255}
 for i:=0; i<=255;i++{

 }
//instead of converting to decimal iterate using byte arrays
```

Alternatively,
How can I divide the range of the byte array (upper-lower) into smaller ranges

```
\\eg 
   l := []byte{0,1}
   r := []byte{1,255}
```

break this into smaller ranges

```
   l := []byte{0 , 1}
   l2:= []byte{x1,y1}
... 
   r:= []byte{1,255}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want a single loop that iterates over 2 slices, one after the other?

Comment: @icza we can think of each byte array or slice as a decimal number. I want to iterate from the "lower decimal" to "upper decimal"

Comment: Please add example input and example output.

Comment: @icza added example

Comment: You added an example input but not output. Specifically I don't understand what this means: _"iterate over all numbers in between lower and upper"_

Comment: @icza is this okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to simply interpret the bytes as a big-endian integer. Since there is no int48 type in Go (i.e. a six bytes large integer), you have to first extend the byte slices with leading zeros until it fits into the next largest type, int64 or uint64. Then interate with a standard for loop and reverse the decoding for each iteration:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/binary"
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        lower := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        lowerInt := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(append([]byte{0, 0}, lower...))

        upper := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255}
        upperInt := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(append([]byte{0, 0}, upper...))

        buf := make([]byte, 8)
        for i := lowerInt; i <= upperInt; i++ {
                binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf, i)
                fmt.Println(buf[2:])
        }
}
// Output:
// [0 0 0 0 0 0]
// [0 0 0 0 0 1]
// ...
// [0 0 0 0 0 254]
// [0 0 0 0 0 255]
```

Try it on the Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/86iN0V47nZi

Comment: What if there is no limit on the number of bytes?

Comment: Use [math/big.Int](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int).